# How do I use Flask Migrate to create a SIMILAR TO constraint?

Tags: python, flask, flask-migrate

I would like to build a constraint on status, using flask migrate. Status does not yet exist.

my model includes this line:

```
status = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=False)
```

I would like to add the following constraint on status in addition to create status:

```
ALTER TABLE inventory ADD CONSTRAINT "StatusCheck" CHECK ("status" SIMILAR TO 'Ordered|Received|Ready|Faulty|Void');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write SQL in your migration scripts. See http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/ops.html#alembic.operations.Operations.execute.

Side note: Flask-Migrate is just a wrapper to Alembic, to make it Flask friendly. So this is really a question about Alembic.